# Вставка данных о клиенте с учетом специфики высоконагруженной системы

Tags: mysql

необходимо составить SQL-запрос:
который позволяет заносить информацию о клиенте, что зарегистрировался (пол, фамилия, имя, отчество, день рождения, телефон, город проживания, логин, пароль) с учетом специфики высоконагруженной системы. Во время составления SQL-запроса необходимо учесть следующее:

- процедура регистрации клиента предполагает введение логина и проверку его на существование в системе;
- после подтверждения логина, осуществляется двукратное введение пароля и занесения информации в таблицу Client;
- при этом, за время от проверки логина до введения пароля, в высоконагруженной системе уже мог зарегистрироваться другой клиент с таким же логином;

Проверку на существование логина в системе я реализовал, а вот как быть с остальными условиями без понятия.

```
insert into mydb_innodb.client (fk_gender, last_name, first_name, middle_name, birthday, 
contact_phone, city,login, password) 
select * from (g.id_gender, 'ТестФамилия', 'ТестИмя', 'ТестОтчество',
STR_TO_DATE("October 25 1997", "%M %d %Y"), '+770660642618', 'ТестГород', 'логин12345678', 
md5('пароль9876576') from mydb_innodb.gender g where g.gender = 'М') as tmp 
where not exists (select login from mydb_innodb.client where login = 'логин12345678');
```

Comment: *как быть с остальными условиями без понятия.* Ну проверка пароля делается на клиенте. Занесение информации - обычным запросом. При этом на поле логина должно быть наложено требование уникальности - и если успел "другой клиент с таким же логином", то будет получена ошибка нарушения уникальности, которую следует обработать и выдать сообщение, что выбранный логин тю-тю...

Comment: @Akina Спасибо большое за помощь.